# How can a LSTM have an output_dim different than the input_dim of the next layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I was looking at this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (1,), input_dim=1, output_dim=6, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (1,), input_dim=1, output_dim=6, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

How can the first layer have an output of dim=6 and then the next layer have an input_dim=1?

## Edit

The code is wrong and Keras simply tries its best as shown in the actual generated model (see how the model doesn't match the code):
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is very confusing and should never be written like this.

In sequential model, Keras respects the `input_shape` of the *first layer only*. All subsequent layers are initialized with the output of the previous layer, effectively ignoring `input_shape` specification. Source code: [`keras/models.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py#L492). In this case, it's `(None, None, 6)`.

The model summary thus looks like this:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 6)           192       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 6)                 312       
=================================================================
```

By the way, keras spits out warnings on this `LSTM` specification, because `input_dim` is deprecated:

> Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True, units=6)`
>
> Update your `LSTM` call to the
>   Keras 2 API: `LSTM(input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=False, units=6)`